# Converting yyyy-mm-dd into dd mm yyyy

Tags: android, simpledateformat

How to convert 2013-06-24 to 24 Jun 2013? I am using the below code.

```
date1="2013-06-24";
SimpleDateFormat d= new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");

try{
date2 =  d.parse(date1);
}catch (ParseException e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I am getting this error "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-06-24" (at offset 4)"

Comment: Update: The classes seen in the Question are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. See the modern solution in [Answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75850647/642706).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need two `DateFormat` instances: One to parse the original `String`, and another to output the one you want.

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
String inputDateStr="2013-06-24";
Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputDateStr);
String outputDateStr = outputFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: Quite helpful. Never thought about this. Thank you. Worked like a Charm

Answer (score 4):

See the first problem is that you are using different delimiters for String and Date.
So either you do "2013-06-24" to "2013 06 24" in String or do new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy") to new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").

And second problem is that you cannot directly change format like this, in String you are having year-month-date format, so first make a Date object with same format than change it to your desired format as below :

```
date1="2013-06-24";

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date dt = format.parse(date1);

SimpleDateFormat your_format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

date2 = your_format.format(dt);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
SimpleDateFormat d= new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
```

with

```
SimpleDateFormat d= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

you have to follow the date1 pattern. Then you can format your parsed date with

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Comment: I changed it, but I am getting this answer "Mon Jun 24 00:00:00 IST 2013"

Answer (score 2):

```
public String getStringFormatted(String datestring) {
    String format = "dd MM yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault());
    return sdf.format(new Date(datestring.replaceAll("-", "/")));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

The `java.util` date-time API and their corresponding parsing/formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) was released as part of the **Java 8 standard library** which supplanted the legacy date-time API and since then it is strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

### Solution using `java.time`<sup>*</sup>

The `java.time` API is based on [ISO 8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require specifying a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse a date/time string which is already in ISO 8601 format. Your given date string, `2013-06-24` is already in ISO 8601 format. You need a `DateTimeFormatter` just for formatting the `LocalDate` which will be obtained by parsing the given date string.

**Note**: The date-time parsing/formatting APIs are `Locale` sensitive and therefore  [never use date-time parsing/formatting APIs without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2013-06-24");
        System.out.println(date);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = date.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2013-06-24
24 Jun 2013
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/yd96Jp)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working on an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
public String inputFormatget (String datestring1) {
        String format = "dd MM yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault());
        return sdf.format(new Date(datestring.replaceAll("-", "/")));
    }

    public String outFormatset (String datestring2) {
        String format = "dd MM yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault());
        return sdf.format(new Date(datestring.replaceAll("-", "/")));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for leaving this answer. Could you please update it with a description/explanation?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String formateDateFromstring(String inputFormat, String outputFormat, String inputDate){

    Date parsed = null;
    String outputDate = "";

    SimpleDateFormat df_input = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, java.util.Locale.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat df_output = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat, java.util.Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        parsed = df_input.parse(inputDate);
        outputDate = df_output.format(parsed);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
    }

    return outputDate;

}

String convertedDate = formateDateFromstring(
    "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "dd/MM/yyyy",
    datestring);

updateInsuranceEventFragmentBinding.edtdate.setText(convertedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic method you can use to get required format.

Usage - getRequiredDateFormat("2019-09-03", "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd MM yyyy")

```
private String getRequiredDateFormat(String inputDate, String inputDateFormat, String outputDateFormat) {

    DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputDateFormat);
    DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputDateFormat);
    Date date = null;

    try {
        date = inputFormat.parse(inputDate);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not parse date {}", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return outputFormat.format(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String idl = "2021-06-30"; String dl=null; try{ SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); Date date = inputFormat.parse(idl); dl = outputFormat.format(date); System.out.println(dl); } catch (ParseException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the accepted answer and not formatted properly as well