# Which Locale (SimpleDateFormat) is "yyyy-MM-dd"?

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I want to convert a date into "yyyy-MM-dd". I am using

```
 val parser = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy") // The original format
 val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
 val output = formatter.format(parser.parse(etDOB.text.toString()))
```

as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324060/converting-yyyy-mm-dd-into-dd-mm-yyyy). But Android studio is warning me to use SimpleDateFormat(String, Locale). Which locale should I use to get output into "yyyy-MM-dd"?

Or is there a better way to achieve this (API 21)? I also have the date in a calendar instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Locale.getDefault()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault(java.util.Locale.Category)) in **SimpleDateFormat**

```
 val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault())
```

Comment: That gave me "Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT+5.30 1995" This is my code: `val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
formatter.parse(etDOB.text.toString()`

Comment: Also, is Locale.getDefault() depends on the locale set in the user device? Won't that change from user to user?